# Failed in error “plugin was built with a different version of package” while debugging

Tags: go, plugins, goland

I built my .so file:

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o test.so
```

and run debug with Goland, then I get the error:

```
Error running agent: could not initialize input inputs.plugin_input: plugin.Open("./plugins_lib/test1"): plugin was built with a different version of package runtime/internal/sys
```

But I can build my main program in my terminal and it will work well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plugin should be compiled with the same flags as the main application.

If the application is compiled using the IDE already, then add the `-gcflags="all=-N -l"` to the above `go build ...` command.

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o test.so
```

In addition,if the IDE is Goland, the build command of the main application can be found at the debug console of Goland.